# Is it possible to use external device as node.js compiler

Tags: node.js

There are plenty of times where forget charger to my university but I can access theirs pc's. Pcs are locked ( no admin privileges ) so I am unable to install node.
I always got with my pi4b which is running ubuntu server.

Is there any possiblity to download node project on pc and use node commands from pi to compile that project ? I can connect via ssh or sftp.

Comment: You don't need admin privileges to use node. (just use it without installing.) You can even run a whole development environment from a USB stick: https://github.com/mjs2020/PortableNodeDevEnv

Comment: Thx a lot. This will get handy @CherryDT